# Global Human Settlement Layer-Rasterio and Fiona

Tags: python, gdal, fiona, rasterio

I've downloaded the Global Human Settlement Layer data from [here](http://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_BUILT_LDSMT_GLOBE_R2015B/). They are huge files, too big for ArcMap or QGIS to handle comfortably so for that reason I decided to mask them. I was only interested in Ireland so I made sure my coordinate system was the same for both the tif and the polygon (Ireland-admin area) before I begun.

I tried to the following code on one of the tifs that I'm interested in.

```
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio import mask

with fiona.open(r"D:\GIS\Global Human Settlement Layer\Built_Eire\IRL_adm0_WEB.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    geoms = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open(r"D:\GIS\Global Human Settlement Layer\Built_Eire\GHS_BUILT_LDS2000_GLOBE_R2016A_3857_38_v1_0\GHS_BUILT_LDS2000_GLOBE_R2016A_3857_38_v1_0_p1.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geoms, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()

out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open(r"D:\GIS\Global Human Settlement Layer\Built_Eire\GHS_BUILT_LDS2000_GLOBE_R2016A_3857_38_v1_0\GHS_BUILT_LDS2000_GLOBE_R2016A_3857_38_v1_0_p1_Masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

The original .tif is 358.5MB, as soon as I try and run this code it started creating a huge file that even after only 9% completion it is 50GB.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to what I may be doing wrong? I presume the file I downloaded was compressed?

Comment: I'm surprised that a 350Mb raster is too large for QGIS or ArcMap

Comment: in fact I can open it fine in QGIS and it's only using 3 cores to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunuts, yes, your source could be compressed. As a sanity check, make sure the footprint of your `out_image` (`out_image.shape[1:]`) is smaller than the footprint of `src`. The `mask()` function should only read pixels from `src` that are within the cumulative spatial extent of your `shapes` and if your output footprint is larger than you expect there may be some odd features in the shapefile or a bug in rasterio.